# Which is better - Storing values in MYSQL as numbers VS actual values?

Tags: database

Which is better - Storing values in MYSQL as numbers VS actual values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three choices: `ENUM` (1-2 bytes), `TINYINT` (1 byte), `VARCHAR` (1+n bytes).  Each has advantages and disadvantages.

If there will be millions of rows, then `VARCHAR` suffers from space consumed.

If the list of allowed values changes *often*, `ENUM` suffers from the need to do `ALTER TABLE`.  OTOH, it is perhaps the fastest and least intrusive `ALTER` if you follow the restrictions.

Performance of the representation 3 choices is about the same; don't worry about that.

I would not make an `ENUM` that has more than a few dozen values; that gets too clunky, though it still fits in 1 byte (up to 255 values).

Any of them can be indexed.  However, the Optimizer will rarely use a single-column index containing a "low cardinality" column.  OTOH, a "composite" index is often beneficial.

Traditionally, "male" and "female" have been only two values.  But now you may need "decline to state", "unknown", and a host of other values.

If you are talking about "country_code", then simply use `CHAR(2) CHARACTER SET ascii` and have US, ES, AR, NZ, RU, etc.  This is a case where the clarity of `CHAR` overrides the other considerations.  Y/N is another example where `CHAR` may be best.

When using `ENUM`, I like to start with `unknown` as the first value, and say `NOT NULL`.

Comment: Thank you. makes sense.

Comment: Thank you. makes sense.

Comment: @FKM - There are a lot of Q&A on this topic, some with stronger opinions than mine on which of the 3 to use.

Comment: You commented at the right time because I need some expert advise.. I am obtaining city from Google Places auto complete when the user adds location to their profile. I want to store the city in my database but I have to do so as VARCHAR as I do not have an indexed list of all cities. Is this ok ?

Comment: One source shows over 3 million cities in the world.  That cannot be done with `ENUM`; `VARCHAR` makes sense.  If you are storing the city for each user, I would simply use `VARCHAR`.

Answer (score 0):

The number one limitation on the overall performance of a database is the size of the dataset.  You should count every byte.  You are talking about storing something in a bit or in the worst case a single byte vs storing it as either a 4 or 6 byte varchar().  Simple math shows you the cost of that decision as you add rows.

For these situations, in MySQL I will use either a CHAR[1] or a tinyint.  For something like "Gender" there are typically 3 mutually exclusive options ('Male', 'Female', 'Unspecified').  In either case, your allocation cost is 1 byte.

Granted you need to decode the value for presentation purposes, but you can do that either with SQL joins or for small static tables like this, in your application as constants or GET routines in a database Model class. I will typically create the foreign key lookup table even if I don't end up using it in the application for the purposes of helping with referential integrity constraints, but you don't absolutely have to do JOINS to all the lookup tables if you don't want to.

This type of design is database driven, fully relational and goes a long way to keep applications from introducing bad data by accident.  If you set things up properly using foreign key constraints, there is no way for the application to introduce values that don't exist.  With an unvalidated VARCHAR() not only are you wasting storage for every row you add, you have a less resilient application as well.

Comment: The number 1 limitation is a lack of indexes.

Comment: @Strawberry Lack of indexes is not a limitation, it is either a choice or a deficiency in the developers understanding of what is needed for query performance.  Since you did bring it up, when indexes are created the same mistake can be amplified as those varchars end up in the indexes using up even more space/memory.  With that said Gender is low cardinality value and usually not something you want to index by itself anyways with a btree index.